# how to add dir to url key in cms page?

Tags: url-key

Is it possible to add a dir to the url key in cms page?

For example:

**CMS page - url key = test.html**

I would like to show it as

```
www.domain.com/cms/test.html
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can change `url key from cms page`[There is option avaulabel for url key in cms edit page]

[image]